# download rate using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, afnetworking, urlsession

I am writing a downloader app with alamofire module using this function I want to show current download rate in MB/s and I really don't know how to achieve this please help me.

---

```
  @IBAction func tapStartButton(_ sender: Any) {



    let fileUrl = self.getSaveFileUrl(fileName: Data[0] as String)
    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        return (fileUrl, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }

    self.request = Alamofire.download(Data[0] as String , to:destination)

        .downloadProgress { (progress) in



        self.progressCircle.progress = progress.fractionCompleted




        cell.progressLabel.isHidden = false


        }

        .responseData { (data) in

            self.Data.removeFirst()
                self.startButton.isHidden = false
                self.pauseButton.isHidden = true

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Alamofire or any other library provides download speed. Developers have to calculate themselves.
You can do it as:

- Take a global variable that saves previous downloaded bytes.
- Use `NSTimer` with 1 sec interval to calculate the speed.

Code Example:

```
  var prevDownloadedBytes: Int = 0
  var totalDownloadedBytes: Int = 0

  func calculateDownloadSpeed(){
   Timer.scheduleWith(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true){
     speed = totalDownloadedBytes - prevDownloadedBytes
     print("Speed is: \(speed) bps")
     prevDownloadedBytes = totalDownloadedBytes 
  }
}

  @IBAction func tapStartButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.request = Alamofire.download(Data[0] as String , to:destination)
        .downloadProgress { (progress) in

        //Set Total Downloaded bytes here
        self.totalDownloadedBytes = progress.fileCompletedCount

        self.progressCircle.progress = progress.fractionCompleted
        cell.progressLabel.isHidden = false
        }
        .responseData { (data) in
            self.Data.removeFirst()
                self.startButton.isHidden = false
                self.pauseButton.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked fine for me i had another question of Progress class in it has a  propertie named estimatedtimeremaining of type int? how can i use it as it seems nil every time

Comment: thank you it worked. aanother question how can i use estimatedtimeremaining in Progress clas the type is int? and when i call it its always nil

Comment: You can check all the details here at Apple's official page.
[link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress)

Comment: i really a serious issue with calculateDownloadSpeed function how can i stop it ? i aalready try if statment with a bool property but its not working of course because the first time its true and it keeps going what should i do?

Comment: @mahadshahib Store your timer object in a variable eg. 

`var timer: Timer!`
`timer = Timer.scheduleWith(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true){....`
And when you need to stop the timer, call `timer.invalidate()`.